# Can I connect BitBucket repo with Amplify without generating a new token every 2 hours?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-amplify

I tried to connect my BitBucket cloud repository with Amplify.
I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66992238/aws-amplify-bitbucket-deployment-issue) and the [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/integrate-a-bitbucket-repository-with-aws-amplify-using-aws-cloudformation.html). I was able to create a working solution with an oauth token and CF:

```
Resources:
  rAmplifyApp:
    Type: AWS::Amplify::App
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref pProjectName
      Repository: !Ref pRepoUrl
      OauthToken: !Ref pAccessToken
```

But this works for 2 hours, then I have to update the token. This means that a new commit in the repo will not be deployed automatically, all the time. Only when also the token is also refreshed.

Is there a way to make this static? Or just a way to connect a BitBucket repo with Amplify without using a token that can expire?